# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen einer Blonden und einer Blondine?

Tags: difference

Ich habe den Eindruck, dass die wörtlichen Bedeutungen gleich sind, aber werden sie in der Praxis gleich verwendet? Haben sie vielleicht unterschiedliche Nebenbedeutungen?

Comment: Lässt sich der Eindruck, dass die Bedeutungen gleich sind, irgendwie belegen? Wie hast du den Eindruck bekommen? Welche Bedeutung(en) haben die Begriffe für dich?

Comment: [2 answering comments deleted](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment?cb=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die reine Wort- Definiton ist identisch: Beide beschreiben jeweils eine Frau mit blondem Haar.

Allerdings haben sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ganz erheblich Bedeutungsunterschiede herausgebildet.

Der Begriff *die Blonde* ist der neutralere der beiden und beschreibt tatsächlich hauptsächlich die Eigenschaft "Haarfarbe".

In Deutschland werden allerdings (vor allem von Männern) verschiedenen Haarfarben verschiedene Charaktereigenschaften zugeschrieben, die in diesem Kontext immer mitschwingen:

Da gibt es die *feurige Rote* oder auch die *rassige Dunkelhaarige*.

Das mitschwingende Adjektiv bei blonden ist *kühl*, also: die *kühle Blonde*.

Ob an diesen Pauschalisierungen was dran ist, kann man sehr schön in [diesem Artikel](https://www.platinnetz.de/magazin/leben/geschlechterrollen/blondinen-bruenette-oder-rothaarige-bestimmen-haarfarben-den-charakter) nachlesen.

Etwas anders verhält es sich da mit dem Begriff *Blondine*. 
Dieser Begriff hat seit den 90ern eine eher negative Konnotation: Einer *Blondine* wird nur eine sehr geringe Intelligenz zugeschrieben. Oder um es im Klartext zu schreiben: Blondinen gelten als doof.

Das hat vor allem mit den in den 90ern stark verbreiteten Blondinenwitzen zu tun und hat sich seither im deutschen Sprachgebrauch verfestigt.

**WICHTIG** (Danke für den Hinweis @Takkat): Ich dachte, ich hätte es durch die Formulierung klar gemacht: Diese *mitschwingenden Charaktereigenschaften* sind natürlich ausgemachter Blödsinn und absolut sexistisch und diskriminierend, auch wenn der Verbindung Haarfarbe <-> Charakter durchaus in manchen wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten eine gewisse Bedeutung beigemessen wird, siehe obigen Link:

> Die verschiedenen Haarfarben entstehen durch eine unterschiedliche Pigmentierung, die wiederum von Hormonen wie Adrenalin, Melanin oder Serotonin bestimmt wird. Genetiker haben auf dieser Grundlage längst bewiesen, dass zwischen der Haarfarbe und dem Temperament des jeweiligen Menschen ein gewisser Zusammenhang besteht.

Comment: Bei statistischen Korrelationen von physischer Erscheinungsform und Charakter von Personen sollte man auch bedenken, dass bestimmte physische Formen der Umwelt der Person ein bestimmtes Verhalten gegenüber der Person aufdrängen (schöne und/oder große Menschen werden anders behandelt als kleine und/oder hässliche). Das wiederum wirkt sich auf die Verhaltensweisen der betroffenen Person aus: Wie offen ist sie gegenüber anderen? Mit welcher positiven oder negativen Erwartung geht sie auf andere zu?

Comment: Gibt es einen Beleg für das "vor allem von Männern"?

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe mal meine Frau gefragt, denn sie ist blond und muss es daher wissen. Sie bestätigt das, was bereits Vulpex in einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46692/gibt-es-einen-unterschied-zwischen-einer-blonden-und-einer-blondine#comment112827_46692) angedeutet hat: Das Wort *»Blondine«* hat eine abwertende Konnotation.

Wenn man von einer abwesenden Frau mit blonden Haaren spricht, und sie als *Blondine* bezeichnet, kann das wertneutral gemeint sein, ist es aber oftmals nicht. Wenn man von einer *Blondine* spricht, geht es meist entweder um das Aussehen der Frau, oder darum, dass sie ihr intellektuelles Potential nicht erkennen lässt.

Spricht man bei einer abwesenden Frau mit blonden Haaren von einer *Blonden*, dann geht es selten darum, das Aussehen zu thematisieren. Abwertende Bemerkungen sind auch hier nicht ausgeschlossen, aber deutlich seltener zu erwarten als bei der Bezeichnung als *Blondine*.

Interessant ist auch die Betrachtung der Häufigkeit beider Wörter im Lauf der Zeit:

[image: Ngram: Blonde, Blondine]
[Ngram: Blonde, Blondine](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Blonde%2CBlondine&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBlonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBlondine%3B%2Cc0)

Vor ca. 1870 wurde zumindest in der Schriftform die *Blondine* häufiger verwendet als die *Blonde*, dann hatte 120 Jahre lang die Blonde die Nase vorne, und seit ca. 1990 sind beide ca. gleichauf.

Comment: "dass sie ihr intellektuelles Potential nicht erkennen lässt". <g> Normalerweise würde man das etwas weniger vorsichtig ausdrücken. (Ich sage übrigens nicht, dass Blondinen doof sind, aber das ist schon ein weit verbreitetes Vorurteil -- meine erste blonde Helferin kannte übrigens selbst die meisten Blondinen-Witze).

Comment: Ich habe mal vor längerer Zeit (~15 Jahre) von einer Studie gelesen, in der untersucht wurde, ob diese Klischees wirklich so verbreitet sind. Fotos derselben Frauen mit verschiedenfarbigen Perücken wurden Testpersonen (k.A. ob nur männlich oder beiderlei Geschlechts) gezeigt, und diese sollten nur aufgrund des Aussehen beurteilen, für wie intelligent sie die betreffende Frau hielten. Interessanterweise wurden normal blonde Frauen *nicht* für weniger intelligent gehalten als brünette oder rothaarige - aber die "Wasserstoffblondinen" wurden tatsächlich als dümmer eingestuft.

Answer (score 2):

Allein der Vergleich der am häufigsten verwendeten Attribute im Google Ngram Viewer zeigt schon, dass die Begriffe unterschiedlich konnotiert sind.

- [*Blondine*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Blondine&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3): hübsch, attraktiv, schlank, jung, groß, üppig, schön, klein, niedlich
- [*Blonde*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Blonde&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3): klein, groß, kühl, jung, hübsch, schön, lang
- [*Brünette*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Br%C3%BCnette&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3): hübsch, klein, schlank, schön, herrlich
- [*Rothaarige*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Rothaarige&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3): klein
- [*Braunhaarige*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Braunhaarige&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3): ./.
- [*Schwarzhaarige*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Schwarzhaarige&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3):  ./.
- [*Dunkelhaarige*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Dunkelhaarige&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3):  ./.
- [*Hellhaarige*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+Hellhaarige&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3):  ./.

Bezeichnend ist, dass für die meisten Haarfarben die Substantive fast gar nicht verwendet werden, was auch die [Häufigkeit im Vergleich](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Blondine%2CBlonde%2CBr%C3%BCnette%2CRothaarige%2CSchwarzhaarige%2CBraunhaarige%2CDunkelhaarige%2CHellhaarige%2C+Blondschopf%2C+Rotschopf&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) zeigt, wo *Rothaarige* allerdings öfter vorkommt als *Brünette*.

Dabei ist zu beachten, dass von diesen nur *Blondine* fast ausschließlich für Frauen verwendet wird, was die Ergebnisse leicht verzerren dürfte. Komposita wie *Wasserstoffblondine* bleiben ebenfalls unberücksichtigt.